# AngularJS- Switching data sets based on filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm just beginning to explore AngularJS. I recently watched a tutorial explaining how to set up a basic filter. I'm now attempting to expand on that concept. I feel like the way that I'm approaching this is very inefficient.

The method used here requires that a new Ctrl be set up for each new data set. If you had 5 different data sets that you wanted to set filters for, it would require 5 different controllers. When I look at my example below, I see a lot of repeated code which makes me thing that this can be done differently.

Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smithd/eUZ7q/1/

```html
<div ng-app="searchApp">
    <div ng-controller="FilterCtrl" class="filter">
        <h1>Search Demo</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div ng-switch on="selection">
            <!-- <div ng-switch-default>default</div> -->
            <div ng-switch-when="avengers">
                <div ng-controller="AvengersCtrl">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
                    <table ng-show="(filteredData = (avengers.cast | filter:search)) && search && search.length >= 1">
                        <tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast | filter:search">
                            <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{actor.character}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="expendables">
                <div ng-controller="ExpendablesCtrl">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
                    <table ng-show="(filteredData = (expendables.cast | filter:search)) && search && search.length >= 1">
                        <tr ng-repeat="actor in expendables.cast | filter:search">
                            <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{actor.character}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item for item in items" class="filter"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: explain what you think is inefficient and why

Comment: This way requires a new Ctrl for each data set. I feel like the same thing could be achieved without that being the case? Maybe I'm mistaken though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's example using one controller for everything and storing the data in a service.

```html
<div ng-controller="FilterCtrl">
        <h1>Search Demo</h1>
        <hr/>
        <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item for item in items" class="filter"></select> <hr/>
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search">
            <table ng-show="(filteredData = (cast | filter:search)) && search && search.length >= 1">
               <tr ng-repeat="actor in cast | filter:search">
                  <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{actor.character}}</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.factory('DataService', function () {
   return { avengers: [...],expendables: [...]}
 });   

app.controller('FilterCtrl', function($scope,DataService){  
  $scope.items = ['avengers', 'expendables'];
  $scope.selection = $scope.items[0];
  /* change data when select changes*/
  $scope.$watch('selection',function(){
    $scope.cast=DataService[$scope.selection];
  })

});
```

**[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sX1BnYpquKNEGw6lizOq?p=preview)**

Comment: This worked great! It seems to make more sense to handle it this way when working with similar information that can be stored in the same file.

Comment: with angular think of data sharing first,when in doubt keep it in a service that can be accessed from other controllers and directives

Comment: What about encompassing both categories in an "ALL" filter? Can this be easily achieved using this method too?

Comment: sure.. use `extend` to merge them